# Ubuntu 13.10 upgrade low graphics failure

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.10, graphics

Running 13.10 on older HP Pavilion with Nvidia G86M [GeForce 8600 GS] chip.  I was using Nvidia driver before update.  After update, no GUI possible.  Even low graphics mode is in loop of trying to run, but still crashes. Can get into TTY only.  Need to change driver to generic or older nvidia version.  Once up an running into GUI, should be able to repair.

Comment: Switched to GDM mode via answer from other questions.  Still no GUI mode.  Only goes into TTY. StartX issues no screen error.  And with new Xorg setup, no more reconfigure command....